# Get parent formname on child window using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have below form tag on parent page  from which i open a popup. i want to get form Name attribute value(i.e "cust-100" ) on popup screen

```
<form  action="/custAction" formName="cust-100">
```

i tried  below

`self.opener.document.$('[name="formName"]').val()` but it gives error

```
TypeError: self.opener.document.$ is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have val() for form control, try using html() function instead.

```
val = $(window.parent.document).find('form').attr("formName");
```

Comment: try this, $(window.parent.document).find('form').attr("formName")

Comment: Can you make a fiddle and try this, alert(window.opener.jQuery("form").attr("formName"));

Comment: Sorry Adil it works. One more thing  i have declared one hidden parameter with attributes id as "formId" and name as "formName"
if i access it with self.opener.$('#formId').val(), i get the right value but when i acces with formname with
self.opener.$('[name="formName"]').val(). i do not get the right value